# Sqlite3 query to obtain the moved items from a deparment

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have searched the query to find a duplicate records, however my requirement is slightly different, I need to find the records that are moved from one department to another. Below is the main table company with the expected ouput underneath that. Sorry for not finding a right format for this post.

```
ID  PKTNUM  DEPT        MONTH
============================    
1   10      acc         Jan
2   20      sales       Feb
3   10      market      Mar
4   30      admin       Apr
5   20      HR          May
6   10      finance     Feb
7   20      sales       Jun
8   30      acc         Jun
9   20      acc         Aug
10  30      finance     Sep


Expected output:
================
[Moved from other dept to ACC]
ID  PKTNUM  DEPT        MONTH
============================  
4   30      admin       Apr
7   20      sales       Jun

[Moved from other dept to Sales]
ID  PKTNUM  DEPT        MONTH
============================  
5   20      HR          May

[Moved from other dept to Finance]
ID  PKTNUM  DEPT        MONTH
============================  
3   10      market      Mar
8   30      acc         Jun



Steps followed to create the table.
----------------------------------
CREATE TABLE COMPANY( ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, PKTNUM INT NOT NULL, DEPT TEXT NOT NULL, MONTH TEXT);

INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (1, 10, 'acc', 'JAN' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (2, 20, 'sales', 'FEB' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (3, 10, 'market', 'MAR' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (4, 30, 'admin', 'APR' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (5, 20, 'HR', 'MAY' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (6, 10, 'finance', 'FEB' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (7, 20, 'sales', 'JUN' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (8, 30, 'acc', 'JUN' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (9, 20, 'acc', 'AUG' );
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,PKTNUM,DEPT,MONTH) VALUES (10,30, 'finance', 'SEP' );
```

This is what i tried, very close to my expected result but not quite OK yet.

```
sqlite> select * from company  a join ( select * from company as a where dept = 'acc') b on a.pktNum = b.pktNum and a.dept != b.dept;

ID          PKTNUM      DEPT        MONTH       ID          PKTNUM      DEPT        MONTH
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
3           10          market      MAR         1           10          acc         JAN
6           10          finance     FEB         1           10          acc         JAN
4           30          admin       APR         8           30          acc         JUN
10          30          finance     SEP         8           30          acc         JUN
2           20          sales       FEB         9           20          acc         AUG
5           20          HR          MAY         9           20          acc         AUG
7           20          sales       JUN         9           20          acc         AUG
```

Comment: Please described what have you tried?

Comment: This is very hard when the month is not a number.

Comment: Please explain how you would do it if month was number.